# My Security & privacy disappears when lanched

Tags: security, privacy

OK. I tried to turn on my firewall but the security & privacy app disapers when lanched. When I click on the app (in Setup), it just disappears. .. Pleas help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for it in the search on the applications menu?

[image]